# Null detection with Linq in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2022

I write the following code in VS2022:

```
var approvalResultHistory = cardData.CardData.SignTicketApproval
                .OrderBy(x => x.CreateTime)
                .Select(x => x.Result)
                .Where(result => result != null)
                .Select(result => new ApprovalResultHistory
                {
                    ApproverName = _wackerUserService.GetUserProfileByEmail(result.ApproverEmail).DisplayName,
                    Outcome = result.Outcome,
                    Comment = result.Comment,
                    CreateTime = result.CreateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
});
```

However, VS told me the "result" in the last **Select** maybe Null and give me a warning. I think I have already excluded all null values in **Where**. Do I miss something? or is VS making a false warning?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a false warning.

Comment: it is possible that cardData.CardData.SignTicketApproval could be null?

Comment: have this code and let's see if the warning goes away. `.Where(result => result != null)
    .Where(result => result.ApproverEmail != null)` ?

Comment: @viveknuna your code does not remove the warning.  instead, the "result" in your second "Where" got a new nullable warning.